# What external influences can a cardiac pacemaker have?

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave

Since in these days there are lots of different devices and appliances which are sending out all kinds of waves or radiation and different strengths (e.g. RFID scanners, induction cookers, Bluetooth, power lines above earth, security scanners, etc. ), I'd like to understand what of these influences in which strengths can influence a cardiac pacemaker or its sensors?

Does anybody have good and detailed reference for this?

Additionally, I'd like to understand in which ways the pacemakers are secured against external influences and what rules and regulations are in place to avoid that newly built technical devices might harm pacemakers?

Comment: They should stay away from MRI scanners and tasers (avoid protests after curfew), and probably not within 50-100m of large broadcast transmitters or military radars.

Comment: They ask you if you have a pacemaker, or any bits of metal in you, **before** letting you near the mri machine... Good idea to answer truthfully...

Comment: Do you ask because you're trying to keep him safe, or trying to find ways to kill him? I'd say from the evidence that things like mobile phones and RFID scanners are quite safe, otherwise the streets would be knee-deep in heart patients. People who operate MRI scanners don't like heart paced people near them. Note that not all pacemakers are programmed the same way.

Comment: I used to do medical device design. Pacemakers, ICDs, and neurostimulators are aggressively tested against a range of hostile electromagnetic environments. Follow the physician's recommendations and there should be no issue. Also, MRI may or may not be contraindicated, it depends on the device and field strength of the scanner - there is an international standard which allows newer devices to obtain an MR-conditional rating, meaning MRI can be used under certain cases at the discretion of the physician and MRI tech. Newer pacemakers are moving this way for diagnostic flexibility.

Comment: @BrianDrummond By "after curfew" you mean "always"

Comment: I'd like to understand the technical details or detailed medical studies on how cardiac devices are protected against external influences. I have read and fully trust high level advice on this (as in the answer below), but want to understand the context in more detail. @Peter: Do you have any links/references to the standards or information on these testing environments you are mentioning?

Comment: The ISO 14708 family is the place to start, it's the standards family for active implantable medical devices. Those standards then call specific other standards depending on device type (IEC 60601, IEC 61000, etc). Also see here for a good overview from Intertek (they offer testing services to med device companies): https://www.intertek.com/medical/electrical-testing/active-implantable-devices/

Answer (score 2):

Bertoit, I'm sure you mean well, but your friend should be discussing this kind of concern with his health professionals, not you. Searching the Internet for medical advice can be a greater hazard than the things you seem worried about.

From the [Mayo Clinic's patient advice re pacemakers](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/pacemaker/about/pac-20384689):

> #### **Special precautions**
>
> It's unlikely that your pacemaker would stop working properly because of electrical interference. Still, you'll need to take a few precautions:
>
> - **Cellphones.** It's safe to talk on a cellphone, but keep your cellphone at least 6 inches (15 centimeters) away from your pacemaker. Don't keep your phone in a shirt pocket. When talking on your phone, hold it to the ear opposite the side where your pacemaker was implanted.
> - **Security systems.** Passing through an airport metal detector won't interfere with your pacemaker, although the metal in it could sound the alarm. But avoid lingering near or leaning against a metal-detection system.
>
>   *To avoid potential problems, carry an ID card stating that you have a pacemaker.*
> - **Medical equipment.** Make sure all your doctors and dentists know you have a pacemaker. Certain medical procedures, such as magnetic resonance imaging, CT scans, cancer radiation treatment, electrocautery to control bleeding during surgery, and shock wave lithotripsy to break up large kidney stones or gallstones could interfere with your pacemaker.
> - **Power-generating equipment.** Stand at least 2 feet (61 centimeters) from welding equipment, high-voltage transformers or motor-generator systems. If you work around such equipment, ask your doctor about arranging a test in your workplace to determine whether the equipment affects your pacemaker.
>
> **Devices that are unlikely to interfere with your pacemaker include microwave ovens, televisions and remote controls, radios, toasters, electric blankets, electric shavers, and electric drills.**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already read many of such high-level advices from clinics etc., but am looking for technical insights. e.g. How does interference actually happen? Does it mess with the sensors or rather break the computer inside? What Voltages do generate electro magnetic fields that could disturb cardiac devices? What fallback mechanisms are in place in cardiac devices in case of interferences? I am looking for medical studies or similar, but having a hard time finding these, because I am not familiar with the medical terminology.